# Multilingual bibliography and automatic indexing

Tags: biblatex, babel, indexing

I use biblatex to build:

- An [automatic index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546554) of the cited author of the bibliography.
- A bibliography in a single language with the [punctuation rules taken from langid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/636313) of each entry.

As discussed in the comments of this last answer,
the solutions work very independently, but I get the following error when trying to mix both:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\blx@nameparser@i ...pandafter {\mblx@currentname
}{\mblx@exemptfields } {\b...
l.142 \footcite{compagnon}
```

I tried to "exempt" the `author` field from the patch, without success.
Is this achievable or would the patch become unreasonable?

Here's a test code, commenting the long patch allows to build the index:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=verbose-trad2,
    singletitle=true,
    indexing=cite,
]{biblatex}

\makeindex
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}}
    {}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mblx@exemptfields}{}
\newrobustcmd*{\ExemptFromLanguageSwitching}{%
  \forcsvlist{\listgadd\mblx@exemptfields}}

\def\blx@thefakelangenv{otherlanguage}%

\def\blx@beglang@fake{%
  \blx@clearlang
  \begingroup
  \ifdef\abx@field@langid
    {\def\blx@endlang@fake{%
       \end{otherlanguage*}%
       \endgroup}%
     \begin{otherlanguage*}{\abx@field@langid}}
    {}}

\let\blx@endlang@fake\relax

\renewrobustcmd*{\blx@imc@printfield}[2][]{%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{#2}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{ffd}{#1}{#2}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@begunit
        \ifinlist{#2}{\mblx@exemptfields}
          {}
          {\let\blx@theformat@outer\blx@theformat
           \def\blx@theformat##1{\blx@theformat@outer{\blx@beglang@fake ##1\blx@endlang@fake}}}%
        \edef\currentfield{#2}%
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\blx@theformat
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter{\csname abx@field@#2\endcsname}%
        \blx@endunit}}}

\catcode`\&=3
\def\blx@printnames#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@ifnameundef{#4}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\def\mblx@currentname{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@thewrapperformat{nwd}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@thewrapperformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{nfd}{#1}{#4}%
        \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
          {\blx@nounit}
          {\blx@begunit
           \blx@namesetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
           \blx@thewrapperformat{\expandafter\blx@nameparser\blx@thedata{}&}%
           \blx@endunit}}}}

\long\def\blx@nameparser@i#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \ifblank{#1}
    {}
    {\setkeys{blx@opt@name}{#1}}%
  \setkeys{blx@opt@namepart}{#2}%
  \expandafter\ifinlist\expandafter{\mblx@currentname}{\mblx@exemptfields}
    {\blx@theformat{#2}}
    {\blx@beglang@fake\blx@theformat{#2}\blx@endlang@fake}%
  \endgroup}

\def\blx@printlist#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@iflistundef{#4}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\def\mblx@currentlist{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@thewrapperformat{lwd}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@thewrapperformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{lfd}{#1}{#4}%
        \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
          {\blx@nounit}
          {\blx@begunit
           \blx@listsetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
           \blx@thewrapperformat{\expandafter\blx@listparser\blx@thedata{}&}%
           \blx@endunit}}}}

\long\def\blx@listparser#1{%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {\blx@listbreak}
    {\ifnum\c@listcount<\c@liststart
     \else
       \expandafter\ifinlist\expandafter{\mblx@currentlist}{\mblx@exemptfields}
         {\blx@theformat{#1}}
         {\blx@beglang@fake\blx@theformat{#1}\blx@endlang@fake}%
     \fi
     \advance\c@listcount\@ne
     \ifnum\c@listcount>\c@liststop
       \expandafter\blx@listbreak
     \fi
     \blx@listparser}}
\makeatother
\catcode`\&=4

\ExemptFromLanguageSwitching{url,doi,eprint,pages}


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{compagnon,
  author     = {Compagnon, Antoine and Someone Else},
  translator = {Même, Moi},
  date       = {1998},
  title      = {Titre: aléatoire?},
  pages      = {306-723},
  langid     = {french},
  url        = {https://example.com/~stuff/more.pdf},
}
@book{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon and Someone Else},
  title        = {Random: title?},
  translator   = {Self, My},
  date         = {1961},
  pages        = {579-588},
  langid       = {english},
  url          = {https://example.com/~stuff/more.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcite{compagnon}
\footcite{glashow}
\printindex
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in [Punctuations rules in multilingual bilbiography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/636226/35864) should have probably not only patched `\printnames` and `\printlist`, but also `\indexnames` and `\indexlist`. (This is now fixed there as well.)

The following code should compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=verbose-trad2,
    singletitle=true,
    indexing=cite,
]{biblatex}

\makeindex
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}}
    {}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mblx@exemptfields}{}
\newrobustcmd*{\ExemptFromLanguageSwitching}{%
  \forcsvlist{\listgadd\mblx@exemptfields}}

\def\blx@thefakelangenv{otherlanguage}%

\def\blx@beglang@fake{%
  \blx@clearlang
  \begingroup
  \ifdef\abx@field@langid
    {\def\blx@endlang@fake{%
       \end{otherlanguage*}%
       \endgroup}%
     \begin{otherlanguage*}{\abx@field@langid}}
    {}}

\let\blx@endlang@fake\relax

\renewrobustcmd*{\blx@imc@printfield}[2][]{%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{#2}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{ffd}{#1}{#2}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@begunit
        \ifinlist{#2}{\mblx@exemptfields}
          {}
          {\let\blx@theformat@outer\blx@theformat
           \def\blx@theformat##1{\blx@theformat@outer{\blx@beglang@fake ##1\blx@endlang@fake}}}%
        \edef\currentfield{#2}%
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\blx@theformat
        \expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter{\csname abx@field@#2\endcsname}%
        \blx@endunit}}}


\catcode`\&=3
\def\blx@printnames#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@ifnameundef{#4}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\def\mblx@currentname{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@thewrapperformat{nwd}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@thewrapperformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{nfd}{#1}{#4}%
        \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
          {\blx@nounit}
          {\blx@begunit
           \blx@namesetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
           \blx@thewrapperformat{\expandafter\blx@nameparser\blx@thedata{}&}%
           \blx@endunit}}}}

\def\blx@indexnames#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@ifnameundef{#4}
    {}
    {\def\mblx@currentname{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@theformat{nid}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {}
       {\begingroup
        \blx@namesetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
        \blx@indexnamesetup
        \expandafter\blx@nameparser\blx@thedata{}&%
        \endgroup}}}

\long\def\blx@nameparser@i#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \ifblank{#1}
    {}
    {\setkeys{blx@opt@name}{#1}}%
  \setkeys{blx@opt@namepart}{#2}%
  \expandafter\ifinlist\expandafter{\mblx@currentname}{\mblx@exemptfields}
    {\blx@theformat{#2}}
    {\blx@beglang@fake\blx@theformat{#2}\blx@endlang@fake}%
  \endgroup}


\def\blx@printlist#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@iflistundef{#4}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\def\mblx@currentlist{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@thewrapperformat{lwd}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@thewrapperformat
       {\blx@nounit}
       {\blx@getformat\blx@theformat{lfd}{#1}{#4}%
        \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
          {\blx@nounit}
          {\blx@begunit
           \blx@listsetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
           \blx@thewrapperformat{\expandafter\blx@listparser\blx@thedata{}&}%
           \blx@endunit}}}}

\def\blx@indexlist#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@imc@iflistundef{#4}
    {}
    {\def\mblx@currentlist{#4}%
     \blx@getformat\blx@theformat{lid}{#1}{#4}%
     \ifdefvoid\blx@theformat
       {}
       {\begingroup
        \blx@listsetup{#2}{#3}{#4}%
        \expandafter\blx@listparser\blx@thedata{}&%
        \endgroup}}}

\long\def\blx@listparser#1{%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {\blx@listbreak}
    {\ifnum\c@listcount<\c@liststart
     \else
       \expandafter\ifinlist\expandafter{\mblx@currentlist}{\mblx@exemptfields}
         {\blx@theformat{#1}}
         {\blx@beglang@fake\blx@theformat{#1}\blx@endlang@fake}%
     \fi
     \advance\c@listcount\@ne
     \ifnum\c@listcount>\c@liststop
       \expandafter\blx@listbreak
     \fi
     \blx@listparser}}
\makeatother
\catcode`\&=4

\ExemptFromLanguageSwitching{url,doi,eprint,pages}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{compagnon,
  author     = {Compagnon, Antoine and Someone Else},
  translator = {Même, Moi},
  date       = {1998},
  title      = {Titre: aléatoire?},
  pages      = {306-723},
  langid     = {french},
  url        = {https://example.com/~stuff/more.pdf},
}
@book{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon and Someone Else},
  title        = {Random: title?},
  translator   = {Self, My},
  date         = {1961},
  pages        = {579-588},
  langid       = {english},
  url          = {https://example.com/~stuff/more.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcite{compagnon}
\footcite{glashow}
\printindex
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always, you post answers faster than I can post questions! I'm checking for side effects. Thanks again.

Comment: An unwanted side effect was finally spotted: the "p." for the page range appears when needed in the bibliography, but never in the footnote where the reference is called. This can be seen in the example calling eg. ```\footcite[36]{compagnon}```

Comment: @letax You need to also exempt the `postnote` field from the language switching.

Comment: Great! Many thanks again.