# Is an author index possible with Biblatex natbib=true

Tags: biblatex, authorindex

I have a voluminous book with the following bibliography setup:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=authoryear, 
            citestyle=authoryear-icomp, natbib=true,
            ibidpage=true]{biblatex}
```

As far as I can tell, packages like authorindex or makeidx won't work with this, right?

Unfortunately, I can't change much on this set-up. I need `natbib` formatting, and bibtex broke in this document a few years ago, and I could never find out what the problem was.

Comment: On the `biblatex` side of things, `natbib=true` within `biblatex` shouldn't be interfering with anything, relying on `backend=bibtex` rather than using `biber` could be an issue though. Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546554/106162) help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks. I can change to biber, but authorindex requires bibtex right? I'm making a keyword index as well via makeidx.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't actually know `authorindex`, but reading [moewe's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546554/106162) it doesn't sound like it's needed and `biblatex` (at least with `biber`) can do the job by itself? This is kind of the default situation with `biblatex`: it's incompatible with similar packages but it can reproduce their functionality.

Comment: Alternatively it seems like the `natbib` package itself can work with `authorindex` according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174389/106162), and depending what you mean by `natbib` formatting (I don't think `natbib=true` in `biblatex` does much more than define `\citet` and other variants of `\cite`) there may be other options.

Comment: Would take someone more qualified to say if `biblatex` and `authorindex` are fundamentally incompatible, but happy to look into a full non-working but compilable example if you can provide.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that solution by Moewe, but it didn't work. Neither did putting in a natbib.cfg file, as would work with natbib proper. I have found a brute force method: us the authorindex command \aionly after, e.g., \citep{author:year}. Then authorindex finds it. I may just go through the book and do this, since I'm using makeidx for an index of keywords.

Comment: Basically, this shows me that, even though in the .aux file there is only the command \citation, authorindex can't see it unless I use the explicit commands of authorindex. If this weren't a document that has several years of work in it, I'd change stuff around, but unless there's a more elegant method I'll search my way through the document and add an \aionly behind citations.

Comment: `bibstyle=authoryear,  citestyle=authoryear-icomp,` is equivalent to the shorter `style=authoryear-icomp,`. Nowadays there is rarely a reason to stick with `backend=bibtex,` instead of `backend=biber,` (of course you may have to adjust your editor settings for Biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Only Biber offers full support of all `biblatex` features. And for `authorindex` the real obstacle is that you use `biblatex`. Whether you use BIbTeX or BibTeX with `biblatex` is pretty much irrelevant for `authorindex` (it won't work out of the box either way).

Comment: Great, thanks for all the comments. I can get biber to work, but due to time constraints I may just take the brute force method with authorindex, as I can get my two indexes most easily that way. My next book will be with biber :)))

Answer (score 0):

`authorindex` isn't directly compatible with `biblatex` (and changing anything in `natbib.cfg` will not do anything for `biblatex` no matter if the `natbib` compatibility mode is used: the `natbib` compatibility mode essentially only enables `natbib` names of some cite commands, see [Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864)).

But as mentioned [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693904/is-an-author-index-possible-with-biblatex-natbib-true#comment1722176_693904) by [Dai Bowen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/106162/dai-bowen) and demonstrated in [How to create an author index using BibLaTeX with Biber backend and APA style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546456/35864) and the example documents linked there, `biblatex` has indexing support out of the box, so there should be no need for `authorindex`.

If you want indexing in a document using `biblatex` I strongly suggest you look into `biblatex`'s built-in capabilities instead of external packages for cite indexing. [How to create an author index using BibLaTeX with Biber backend and APA style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546456/35864) and the example documents linked there can be a start, but if your document setup is already more complicated when it comes to citations, the bibliography or indexing and you cannot manage to get anything going based on the link, I suggest you ask a new question with a compilable example document and a clear description of what you want to achieve.